# Help on a Complicated MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

Three Tables: **User**, **Question** and **Answer**

Table Answer has columns: AnswerID, UserID, QuestionID and Score.

a user can submit answer to a question **more than once**. But when ranking only the highest score he earned on the question should be counted.

Now I need get the rank (UserID, total points). How to write the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the full context of your query, but something like this should help:

```
SELECT QuestionID, UserID, MAX(Score) FROM Answer GROUP BY UserID, QuestionID
```

**EDIT**

Based on OP Comment, query should be more like this:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(SELECT Max(Score) FROM Answer GROUP BY UserID, QuestionID) AS TotalScore GROUP BY UserID
```

To be honest I'm not sure if the subquery is 100% correct so you might not get the exact result you want, but the basic form of it is right.

Comment: I think he wants the sum of the maxs for each question

Comment: I need something like: select sum(max(score)), UserID from.... group by UserID, ProblemID

Answer (score 1):

First select highest scored answers, then calculate total points.

```
SELECT
  UserID, SUM(Score) AS TotalPoints  
FROM (
  SELECT
    UserID, QuestionID, MAX(Score) AS Score
  FROM
    Answer
  GROUP BY
    UserID, QuestionID
) AS sq
GROUP BY
  UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

> But when ranking only the highest
>   score he earned on the question should
>   be counted.

Based on this what I understand is that you want the max score of each question for every user and then rank them

```
 SET @rank=0;
     SELECT 
          UserId,
          Sum(Points) as TotalPoints,
          Rank
        FROM
(
        SELECT UserID,MAX(Score) as Points,(@rank:=@rank+1) as Rank from Answer
        group by UserID,questionId
        order by  Points
) as d1
group by d1.UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a sub query like this:

```
SELECT UserId, SUM(
SELECT MAX(SCORE) FROM Answer a
WHERE a.uestionId = q.questionId)
FROM Question q
WHERE q.userId = 1234
Group by userid
```